Update your target API level by August 31, 2024 to release updates to your app
I received this message from google play store for both my application. This is weird, because android 15 is not released and my target SDK is 34. Target SDK 34 is ok, I guess.
Message:

Information from google play console:

Can someone explain what is going on? Is it mistake or I did something wrong?

No, It is required by Google Play Store from August.
Your app must target Android 14 i.e. API Level 34.
You can ignore this notification sent by Google Play if your application is already targeting Android 14.

I found the answer, seems the message related to beta versions, not production, google play console should send more specific warning...
